# d3 orbital using transform rotate

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I wanted to know where my math is off or if there is a better way of achieving what Im trying to accomplish with d3. Essentially I have a circle of rotation with a given radius that I want to rotate an arbitrary number of smaller shapes around similar to this orbital example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/djvanderlaan/4953593). But the thing is I dont want to use a timer since my scenario involves rotating the small circles along the radius of the larger circle with equal angles of rotation in between each one. So for example the first circle would rotate along the radius to 315 degrees and the next to 270 and so on until each one is an equal distance away. This was assuming I had 8 smaller circles so the angle in between them would be 45 degrees. The problem is that calling rotate for an angle greater than 180 degrees causes the orbit to happen in the wrong direction.

```
var dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var width = 600,
    height = 600,
    rad = Math.PI / 180,
    layerRadius = 10,
    radius = width / 2,
    step = 360 / dataset.length,
    svg = d3.select('#ecosystem')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

var layers = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

layers.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'planet')
    .attr('cx', 0)
    .attr('cy', -height / 2)
    .attr('r', layerRadius)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .style({
    'stroke': 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
});

svg.selectAll('.planet')
    .transition()
    .duration(600)
    .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 120;
})
.ease('cubic')
.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    //angle should be 360 - step * (i + 1);
    console.log(360 - step * (i + 1));
    var angle = 360 - step * (i + 1);
    return "rotate(" + angle + ")";
});

//circle of rotation    
var c = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', width / 2)
    .attr('cy', height / 2)
    .attr('r', radius)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .style({
    'stroke': 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
});

//center point
var cp = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', width / 2)
    .attr('cy', height / 2)
    .attr('r', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .style({
    'stroke': 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunwallace/Sk3CW/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to animating a pie chart (see e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)), you need a custom tween function -- the default interpolations aren't really suitable for anything radial. Fortunately, this is relatively straightforward, you just need to tell D3 how to interpolate the angle, which in this case is a straightforward number interpolation.

```
function angleTween(d, i) {
            var angle = 360 - ((i+1)*20);
            var i = d3.interpolate(0, angle);
            return function(t) {
                return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
            };
        }
```

Then, instead of specifying `transform` directly, give it this function:

```
.attrTween("transform", angleTween);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk3CW/4/).

Comment: Thanks so much! So essentially tween can be run on a given attribute and the interpolation function estimates the x,y coordinates for each tween or whatever the start and end points are for a given attribute. In my case the beginning angle or 0 and the final angle?

Comment: Yes -- except that it's a simple interpolation between two values (e.g. calling it with 0.5 gives you the mid point). The point of the tween function is to tell D3 how to interpolate something that's not obvious. E.g. interpolating between "rotate(0)" and "rotate(180)" (as strings) isn't. This tween function is only setting a single value, the rotation angle.